# Oracle INSERT SELECT, with coldfusion cfqueryparam BLOB type

Tags: oracle, coldfusion

lets make it simple, hope you guys can help and understand

```
<cfsavecontent variable="sContent">
    <cfoutput>
        here i will have alot of Text will needed to INSERT SELECT into database

    </cfoutput>
<cfsavecontent>


<!--- perform insert select --->
<cfquery name="Inserting" datasource="#data#">
    insert table1 (content)
    select <cfqueryparam value = "#sContent#" CFSQLType = "CF_SQL_BLOB">
    from dual
</cfquery>
```

reason i use blob, because my content that insert into database is contain large amount of text. 
is this the correct way to  insert blob data?

Comment: Why are you trying to use `cfqueryparam` for an insert from a database table itself?

Comment: `insert table1 (content)
    select sContent
    from dual` is enough right?

Comment: sContent more than 4000 characters,  DDL statement were get an error about cannot bind long .

Comment: Why `BLOB` for text data? You could use a `CLOB` since that is intended for large amounts of text.

Comment: reason use insert select because want to get rid of the cfloop insert into
performance issue

Comment: What is the problem you are encountering?  Also, is the missing keyword `into` restricted to this question, or is it in your code as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
<cfquery name="Inserting" datasource="#data#">
    INSERT INTO table1 (
      content
    ) VALUES (
      <cfqueryparam value = "#sContent#" CFSQLType = "CF_SQL_BLOB" />
    )
</cfquery>
```

or using cfscript:

```
insertBlob = new Query( sql = "INSERT INTO table1 ( content ) VALUES ( :content )",  datasource = data );
insertBlob.addParam( name  = "content", value = sContent, cfsqltype = "CF_SQL_BLOB" );
insertBlob.execute();
```

Comment: is it possible to have insert select approach? i'll need it just because of some reason

Comment: It would help to know the other reason - are you actually doing `SELECT ... FROM DUAL` or are you selecting from an actual table?